# Problems using $interval to create a live feed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

So i'm just getting into using the MEAN stack and am creating a live feed.  I've made an API that basically sends data to my DB.  I've then used Angular to create a live feed of the data being sent to the DB.

I'm using `$interval` in my controller with `$http.get()` to grab data from my api every .5 seconds.

Is there anything wrong with doing it this way?  Is there a better way that a noob like me would be able to understand and implement?

Comment: Use sockets instead of AJAX.

Comment: I second Tushar, polling every 0.5 seconds is a very bad idea.